# Scrapy integration with DjangoItem yields error

Tags: django, scrapy

I am trying to run scrapy with DjangoItem. When i run crawl my spider, I get the 'ExampleDotComItem does not support field: title' error. I have created multiple projects and tried to get it to work but always get the same error. I found [this](https://ruddra.com/posts/django-1-7-scrapy/) tutorial and downloaded the source code, and after running it; I get the same error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py",line 654, in _runCallbacks
>      current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw) 
>   File "C:\Users\A\Desktop\django1.7-scrapy1.0.3-master\example_bot\example_bot\spiders\example.py", line 12, in parse
>        return ExampleDotComItem(title=title, description=description)
>   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy_djangoitem__init__.py", line 29, in **init**
>       super(DjangoItem, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\item.py", line 56, in **init**
>       self[k] = v
>   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\item.py", line 66,
>   in **setitem**
>       (self.**class**.**name**, key)) KeyError: 'ExampleDotComItem does not support field: title'

Project structure:

```
├───django1.7-scrapy1.0.3-master
   ├───example_bot
   │   └───example_bot
   │       ├───spiders
   │       │   └───__pycache__
   │       └───__pycache__
   └───example_project
       ├───app
       │   ├───migrations
       │   │   └───__pycache__
       │   └───__pycache__
       └───example_project
           └───__pycache__
```

My Django Model:

```
from django.db import models

class ExampleDotCom(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

My "example" Spider:

```
from scrapy.spiders import BaseSpider
from example_bot.items import ExampleDotComItem

class ExampleSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
         title = response.xpath('//title/text()').extract()[0]
         description = response.xpath('//body/div/p/text()').extract()[0]
         return ExampleDotComItem(title=title, description=description)
```

**Items.py:**

```
from scrapy_djangoitem import DjangoItem
from app.models import ExampleDotCom

class ExampleDotComItem(DjangoItem):
    django_model = ExampleDotCom
```

**pipelines.py:**

```
class ExPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        print(item)
        item.save()
        return item
```

**settings.py:**

```
import os
import sys

DJANGO_PROJECT_PATH = '/Users/A/DESKTOP/django1.7-scrapy1.0.3-master/example_project'
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = 'example_project.settings' #Assuming your django application's name is example_project

sys.path.insert(0, DJANGO_PROJECT_PATH)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
BOT_NAME = 'example_bot'



import django
django.setup()
SPIDER_MODULES = ['example_bot.spiders']

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'example_bot.pipelines.ExPipeline': 1000,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you show your Django model? This is likely occurring because `title` isn't defined on your `ExampleDotCom` model.

If it is there, perhaps you need to run your Django migrations?